# AEM Docusign Integation

Tags: docusignapi, aem

While trying to integrate `Docusign` with AEM, I added following maven dependency :

```
<groupId>com.docusign</groupId>



<artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
```

2.9.0

After resolving all the dependencies required by above jar, my bundle is active, but still I am getting following error when trying to access the `ApiClient` provided my `docusign` SDK

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: Could not initialize

```
classcom.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes
```

Comment: Have you considered a no-code solution like https://tray.io/connectors/adobe-experience-manager-docusign-integrations ?